# Watson Assistant - how to set a condition with "<" and ">" that works with time?

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, watson-conversation, watson-assistant

I'm trying to use this expression `@sys-time >'19:00:00' || @sys-time <'8:00:00'` as **if** on watson assistant but it is recgnising any time as input. Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

There is expression language that allows you to work with dates.

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-methods.html#date-time

Your example would be:

```
@sys-time.after('19:00:00') || @sys-time.before('8:00:00')
```